# Why does my TV make noise when receiving a call on cellphone placed near it?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life

I had a CRT TV some times back. I noticed that most of the times, when the TV was on, it made certain kind of noise just few seconds before the cellphone placed near it starts to ring. This was cool as my TV predicted that I'm about to recieve a call.

Does anyone know why and how does it happen?

Comment: From electronics SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303259/why-do-cell-phones-sometimes-interfere-with-amplifiers